# Looping through array and back to beginning when reaching end

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple array

```
var answerAttribute = ['A','B','C','D'];
```

I have 16 list items, what I'm trying to accomplish is loop through the length of the list and regardless of if the list 2 items or 300. I'd lke to have a data attribute associated with it of A,B, C or D.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
var questionOption = '';
for(var i = 0; i < quizContent.length; i++) {
    questionOption = answerAttribute[i % answerAttribute.length];
    console.log(questionOption);
}
```

When logging this to the console, it logs A, AB, ABC, ABCD, ABCDundefined, and keeps repeating undefined until it's reached the loops conclusion. My question is what am I doing incorrectly so that it only logs one letter per loop.

Comment: What's your question? Your condition should be `<`, not `<=`. Other than that, I don't know what your specific issue is.

Comment: Prematurely posted, finishing the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ah, premature askulation. It happens. :D

Comment: adding to @clockwork comment `answerAttribute[i]` should be changed  to `answerAttribute[i%4]`otherwise you'll get `index Out of bond` if quizContent.length >3

Comment: I guess you want sth like `for(var i = 0; i <  quizContent.length; i++) questionOption += answerAttribute[i % answerAttribute.length];` but its hard to tell. Please rephrase your description...

Comment: Oh, yeah I see what you're getting at. Using the modulus like others noted seems to be what you want. You could also use a secondary counter that resets to `0` when the `answerAttribute` length is reached, but the modulus is nicer.

Comment: If you just want to log one character, why doing `+=`? Just do  `=`.

Comment: @user9274775 What a good laugh! This gave away the gender of each of us however..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
questionOption += answerAttribute[i]
```

This statement is short-form for `questionOption = questionOption + answerAttribute[i]`. It will append the next element to `questionOption` in every iteration of the loop.

It looks like what you want is probably `questionOption = answerAttribute[i]`. This will replace the value in `questionOption` with the new element instead of appending it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. With that said, that was exactly what I needed but however after the arrays conclusion(reach 'D'), it started outputting undefined. However, I combined your suggestion with @Jonas W and seemed to have reached a conclusion. I have updated my code to reflect. Thank you!

Comment: As others have mentioned, it outputs `undefined` because your `answerAttribute` array has only 4 elements, but the value of `i` could be larger, depending on the length of `quizContent`.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply log only the current value, like this:

```
var questionOption = '';
for (var i = 0; i < quizContent.length; i++) {
    //what is questionOption used for?
    questionOption += answerAttribute[i];
    console.log(answerAttribute[i]);
}
```

or if you want `questionOption` to refer to the current value

```
questionOption = answerAttribute[i];
console.log(questionOption );
```

Comment: You'll get undefined if `quizContent.length>3`

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal -- no `Index out of Bound` in Javascript!

Comment: @Malvolio I mean't `undefined` :p

Comment: If there is no answer for the question, I guess having a undefined would make sens tbh

Answer (score 1):

You're looping the `quizContent` indexes and applying them to the `answerAttribute` array. I believe what you want is a nested loop...

```js
var quizContent = Array(10); // assume you have 10 quiz questions...
var answerAttribute = ['A','B','C','D'];
for (var i = 0; i < quizContent.length; i++) {
    // generate a string for each quiz option
    var questionOption = '';
    for (var n = 0; n < answerAttribute.length; n++) {
        questionOption += answerAttribute[n];
    }
    quizContent[i] = questionOption;
    console.log(questionOption);
}

console.log(quizContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I doubt that the question is actually about the logging, and is actually about the resulting string.

Either way, I'd do this without loops.

```js
var answerAttribute = ['A','B','C','D'];

var quizContent = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];

var questionOption = answerAttribute
     .join("")
     .repeat(Math.ceil(quizContent.length / answerAttribute.length))
     .slice(0, quizContent.length);
     
console.log(questionOption);
```

It just joins the `answerAttribute` into a string of characters, and repeats that string the number of times that the length of `answerAttribute` can be divided into `quizContent.length` (rounded up).

Then the final string is trimmed down to the size of the `quizContent` to remove any extra content from the rounding up.

Note that this approach assumes a single character per attribute. If not a single, but they're all the same length, it can be adjusted to still work.

Comment: in the spirit of functional programming.. `quizContent = Array(15).fill(1)`

Comment: also, he said "data-attributes" so i'm assuming he'll have to append the string as a data attribute to an element, which would require a loop

Comment: Yeah, that could be. Just wanted to give a different approach.